# React - How can a functional component use a 'this' property

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a page where there are multiple instances of the same  functional component inside a parent component. Upon clicking anywhere inside the parent component I want each individual child component to check if the 'event.target' is equal to itself, if it **isn't**, then I want it to do something.

Maybe I got the wrong idea about this, but is there a way to use a 'this' property inside a function component or a way to mimic it?

edit: some code

**Parent component:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import ShopppingListItem from './ShoppingListItem'

function ShopppingList(){
    const [list, setList] = useState([{id: 0,text: 'dfdsdf'}, {id: 1,text: 'dfdsdf'},
    {id: 2,text: 'dfdsdf'}, {id: 3,text: 'dfdsdf'}]) //shopping list example
    const [clickedTarget, setClickedTarget] = useState(null)

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        setClickedTarget(e.target)
    }

    return(
        <ol
            className='shopping-list-container'
            onClick={handleClick}
            >
            {
                list.map(item => {
                    return <ShopppingListItem key={item.id} item={item} clickedTarget={clickedTarget}/>
                })
            }
        </ol>
    )
}

export default ShopppingList
```

**Child component:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function ShoppingListItem(props){
    const id = props.item.id
    const [text, setText] = useState(props.item.text)
    const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false)

    const clickedTarget = props.clickedTarget

    const inputStyle={
        width: "15vw",
        border:"0px",
        font:"400 20px Segoe UI",
        paddingLeft:"1px"
    }

//////////////////////////////////////
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (this != clickedTarget) //the idea behind what im trying to achieve
            { do something }
      }, [clickedTarget])
//////////////////////////////////////

    const handleTextClick = () => {
        setEditMode(!editMode)
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setText(e.target.value)
    }

    return(
        <div className='shopping-list-item'>
                <span style={{paddingRight:"5px"}}>{id}. </span>
                {!editMode
                    ? <span onClick={handleTextClick}>{text}</span>
                    : <input
                        ref={element}
                        style={inputStyle}
                        type="text" 
                        value={text} 
                        placeholder={text}
                        onChange={handleChange} 
                    />}

        </div>
    )
}

export default ShoppingListItem
```

Comment: Can you share some code in order to be able to help you?

Comment: Functional component are instance less that they do not have `this` in them. I am not able to get what exactly you want to do